# Изменить (стилизовать) выпадающий список Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Пожалуйста помогите. 
Кто знает как можно изменить структуру drop down Woocommerce, чтобы была возможность стилизовать его?

Чтобы можно было сделать как этот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю можно редактировать этот файл.

> mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f4e7ffd1805ee1f945a44f45f8be4e00873b03e5/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php

Но я не совсем знаю как это сделать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

> Но я не совсем знаю как это сделать.

Любая "стилизация" - это css. Вне зависимости от движка.

Задание правил css в WordPress делается в файле(ах) стилей [[дочерней](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B)] темы или кастомайзере (внешний вид-настройки)- дополнительные стили.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласна, но css здесь не поможет, так как нет возможности стилизовать <select> и <option>. К примеру, тема Avada или Contentberg, если вы знаете, использует такую возможность, как изменить структуру, то есть перезаписать файл так, как удобно, без использования <select> и <option>.

Comment: Нужно учить css и тогда всё помогает.